# DNS: A record conflicting with mx, cname etc

Tags: domain-name-system

I have an a record (*) which points all traffic for *.sub.domain.com  (i.e. test.sub.domain.com) to a public IP
Visiting test.sub.domain.com correctly directs me to my IP. Woot.

I then added the following records:

cname: autodiscover.test-> autodiscover.outlook.com
mx: test-> test-sub-domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
txt: test -> v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

After I update the DNS visiting rest.sub.domain.com no longer works

I know cname records can conflict with A records etc  - so I was surprised! Suggestions?

Comment: Exactly what no longer works? Be specific. Also you should include the real domain name ([why we ask for this](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)).

Comment: CNAME conflicts with everything. Basically, if you have a CNAME, all the other records are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

I was using a wild card A record. Wildcards only expand to names that dont exist